# Weird php require/include error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a relatively new to development but do know a few stuff.

I was doing a tutorial on PHP Beyond the basics from Lynda and was trying to make the database class.

after everything was written in the class, i tried to see if the connection is made.

```
require_once("../includes/database.php");
if(isset($database)) {
    echo "true<br />";
}else {
    echo "false<br />";
}
```

the above code was my test to see if it was allright

the problem was when i tried to use "require_once("config.php");" in the database class.

```
require_once("config.php");//line 13

class MySQLDatabase{
   //code that is not important for this issue
}
```

this gave me the following error(s) on the page:

```
 Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in       E:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

 Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in E:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

 Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in      E:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
 Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in E:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

 Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in E:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

 Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in E:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
```

Database connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

If i used (code below) instead of the require/require_once/include/include_once part it worked!

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "gallery");
define("DB_PASS", "123465");
define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
```

It's not the first time i use require/include...but i'm really baffled why this doesen't work with this method :-/
(I'll change everything to mysqli once i finish with the DB class as it is the tutorial. And no, I don't have access to the exercise files)

(sorry for the long post)

Comment: There may be some problem in 'config.php'.

Comment: It seems that in config.php you do not define the Constants the way you did in your example.
As it states, the Constants in the config.php seem to be missing (curly) braces in their definition.
Add the coinfig.php to the question (just replace the login, pass and host with blanks)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like in your config.php you're missing the quotes while defining your constants.

```
wrong:
define(DB_SERVER, "localhost");
right:
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
```

Double check that, or post the relevant sections from your config.php :)

Comment: It's actually the use of the constants in `mysql_connect()` throwing the errors, since they were never defined in the first place.

Comment: While this is a correct suggestion, it could not be the cause of the problem. The message in the notice itself says that `DB_SERVER` is treated as `"DB_SERVER"` if not already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the constants in the following way.

```
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "gallery");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "123456");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
```

to remove `Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER` Notice.

And it look like either we are missing something or your mysql database is down ?

Comment: OK... fixed it but in a way i didn't tought it would do anything because it sounded a bit absurd.

i just renamed the file from "config.php" to "conf.php" ... i had the impression that it would somehow conflict with some other file from xampp with the same name.

I allso changed the way i defined them with the way that user1912855" stated (but it also worked the old way).

I didn't thought it would conflict with some other file, seeing how I gave the path specifically to my includes folder...

Thanks for the responses guys !